# Dead start menu search entry

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I recently replaced an Eclipse 2018-09 installation with Eclipse 2019-03. Strangely, the Eclipse 2018-09 still shows up under 'All' and 'Apps' during a start menu search. I can't do anything with this shortcut, left and right clicking anywhere has no effect.

It is not a deprecated link in the start menu folder.
It is not a deprecated link anywhere to be found on my HDD.
It is just... there.

I tried:

- Rebuilding the search index
- Unticking everything in the search index settings
- Deleting the Window.edb file manually
- Restarting the search service/computer
- Rebuilding the search index
- Searching the registry for '2018-09'

I found something in the registry under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\bam\UserSettings\S-1-5-21-189534607-2389982409-2979425644-1001`. There was an entry pointing to the old eclipse.exe on HarddiskVolume4 (FAT32 system partition). Deleting it had no effect.

Even after having brought the search index down to one entry (I hope it's not that shortcut, I don't know why it shows '1' after deleting everything) it still shows up.

Comment: Do you have disabled "run apps in background"?

Comment: Yes, I did. After enabling it, the icon of the shortcut was gone. I rebuilt the (empty) index, deleted the .edb file, restarted. Now It's completely gone. Many thanks! I wouldn't have figured this ouf myself. Why on earth is Windows Search coupled to those apps? All I see there is Alarm, Calculator, Maps and other unimportant stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to enable background apps.

Go to Settings -> Privacy -> Background apps.

Below, turn apps and services settings On.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4468230/windows-10-background-apps-and-privacy-microsoft-privacy

Maybe somebody can explain why.

Comment: My guess is that this has something to do with the "Cortana" app running in background. I first had enabled background apps but disabled Cortana which did not solve the problem. Only enabling Cortana did the trick.